# Building NAS Server and Need Guidance

Tags: usb, system-installation, ssd, nas, zfs

I'm building a NAS and using Ubuntu as the OS. I have a few questions and need some guidance on what direction to take. I know I am asking many questions, if you can only answer one of them please feel free to answer only it.

For reference this is the hardware I'm using. This will be important later on. I currently have this all together running.

- HP N54L Micro Server
- Modified BIOS to allow full speed on SATA
- Upgraded to 16GB ECC Ram
- 5 x 4TB Seagate NAS Drives
- 1 x 120 GB Kingston SSD
- 2 x 32 GB Lexar USB 3.0

I am planning on using ZFS to create a pool of data and some redundancy. I want to use the SSD as a L2ARC.. maybe ZIL as well, but it might not benefit me. This is not for a business.. this is just a home project for personal use and fun.

Originally I was going to use the SSD for the cache for ZFS, OS Install, and swap. Though I was concerned that a large amount of wear would be on the SSD and I could loose the OS if this drive died. I'm thinking about installing Ubuntu to a USB Flash Drive. I have a fast 3.0 USB flash drive... the system does have a onboard USB 2.0 port inside the case I was planning on using. I know that I'm going to be limited by the speed of the bus, though I figured this would be better going with a USB 3.0 stick on a 2.0 bus and being limited by the bus and not the flash memory speed. I figured if the SSD died this would allow the system to stay operating with maybe some reconfiguration. Am I right here?

If I place the swap on the SSD to speed things up and have less wear on the USB flash drive. Will I still be able to boot if the SSD drive dies and I have no swap partition?

What size should my swap be. I have 16 GB of ram. I read the old way was the same amount of swap for ram. I also read that 8 GB would be good and 0.5 x the amount is a good start. I also read that I might not need swap with that amount of ram.

Is there anything else I could or should move to the SSD to make the system run better? Though remember that I have concerns the SSD could wear out so this would be something not important for boot or that could be lost if the drive dies.

Is there anything I should disable when running from USB to increase performance.

If I want to mirror my OS USB stick to the other extra  memory USB memory stick to allow for a backup if the stick dies. How would I do this what would I use. Is it possible to have it backup daily the OS partition to another USB Flash Drive.

Is there a better way of doing this with the hardware I have. Basically I want redundancy if my SSD dies and I want to be able to backup the current OS daily or so to a USB Flash Drive.

Let me know if I need to explain anything out more.

Comment: Why not have two SSDs in RAID 1 for redundancy?

Comment: I'm limited to 6 SATA Ports and by the room in the case itself. It's pretty packed. I could add a card to provide more ports and maybe fit a SSD between the bays. Which is a possibly. That's a good idea.

Comment: Unless you already have the HP server, you could think about doing a self-build, and buy a motherboard with more than six SATA ports. You would probably save a tonne of money too.

Comment: I already have the server. I got a extremely good deal on it. I think I'm going to take your approach and do the raid SSD. This will eliminate so many other questions I had and I'm fairly sure how to do this. Adding a SSD and expansion card isn't too much added expense and it allows for further expansion down the road. Thanks for your advice.